# Почему в python не помогает \n при записи в файл?

Tags: python

Вот код.

```
with open('/home/yasinskiy/mbase/result8.txt', 'w') as file:
    a=datasTDay['MozhT'].mean()
    b=datasTDay['GagT'].mean()
    file.write("Средние значения: Можайск %.2f\n" %a)
    file.write("Средние значения: Гагарин %.2f" %b)
    #file.write('Среднее по Можайску = {:.2f}' .format(a))
    #file.write('Среднее по Гагарину = {:.2f}' .format(b))
    file.close()
print(f"Средние значения: Можайск {a:.2f}, Гагарин {b:.2f}")
```

Проверено: при использовании формата % или другого способа форматного вывода в файл, не работает \n: обе строки пишутся подряд. Причина неясна.

Comment: Открывайте файл не в Блокноте, а каком-нибудь другом редакторе, который нормально поддерживает переносы строк

Comment: Спасибо! Никогда бы не подумал, что блокнот может быть виноват!

Comment: Вот если поставите последнюю версию Windows 10, тогда в Блокноте и открывайте) https://habr.com/post/358154/

Comment: Как альтернатива, можно писать `\r\n` — именно такие переносы понимает Блокнот

Comment: Можно при открытии указать требуемый вариант переноса строк: `open('/home/yasinskiy/mbase/result8.txt', 'w', newline='\r\n')`